# How to load a trained neural network (using neuroph) load in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, neural-network

I am using neuroph to image recognition with neural network. To train data I have been following the instructions in this link: http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html 
 And I want to use this in netbeans and I have used the code they have given in this given link above. In this process I face few problems;

1. In this link the trained neural network can be saved by simply clicking on 'save' option but I couldn't. All I could do is 'save all'
2. Wen I use this code and provide the name of my neural network it gives me this:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.neuroph.core.exceptions.NeurophException: Could not read neural
>   network file! at
>   org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.load(NeuralNetwork.java:661) at
>   imagerecognitionsample.ImageRecognitionSample.main(ImageRecognitionSample.java:25)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find file:
>   TrialNetwork.nnet at
>   org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.load(NeuralNetwork.java:653) ... 1 more
>   Java Result: 1

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried entering the full path of the file? What is your current working directory?

Comment: @BretC Yeah I tried giving the whole path to the trained network. Still no luck. I am suppose to copy the trained neural network into one folder in my netbeans  code. I did that too but still giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is an example of loading an nnet file in java neuroph (this will not work if your nnet file is saved from neuroph studio)

```
// create MultiLayerPerceptron neural network

MultiLayerPerceptron neuralNet = new MultiLayerPerceptron(TransferFunctionType.SIGMOID,inputsCount, 22, outputsCount);

// set learning rule

MomentumBackpropagation learningRule = (MomentumBackpropagation) neuralNet.getLearningRule();
learningRule.setLearningRate(0.2);
learningRule.setMaxError(0.01);

//after playing around with this neuralNet, we can save it as:

System.out.println("Saving network");
neuralNet.save("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\MyNeuralNetAnimals.nnet");

Next time, if you want to load that neuralNet, instead of creating new network, dataset, and do all the learning stuffs again:

NeuralNetwork neuralNet = NeuralNetwork.load("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\MyNeuralNetAnimals.nnet");

MomentumBackpropagation learningRule = (MomentumBackpropagation) neuralNet.getLearningRule();
```

Keep in mind this code can only load nnet file that was saved by the code above. Otherwise if you save it from neuralph studio and try to load it this way, it won't work.
Hope this can help.

Comment: saving and loading the network seems to wipe all weights

Comment: StackOverflowError